# Submit trigger does not work

Tags: javascript, jquery, codeigniter-3

I am trying to trigger a form submit after validation, but my trigger does not seem to work. Can anyone help?

Here is my form.

```
<form id="contactform" action="<?= base_url(); ?>" method="post">
<div class="column one-second">
    <input placeholder="Your name" type="text" name="name" id="name" size="40" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false" />
</div>
<div class="column one">
    <input type="button" value="Send" id="submit" onClick="check_email();">
</div>
```

Here is my script.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function check_email() {

    var name = $.trim($('#name').val());

    if (name == "") {
        error = true;
        errortext = "<p>Please enter a name.</p>";
    }

    if (error) {
        $('#error_text').html(errortext);
    } else {
        $('#contactform').trigger('submit');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The button type=submit then form will be submit.

Comment: Wow! That was really easy. Thank you!

Comment: Not that easy. The form will be submitted even if it contains errors.

Comment: for this you can return true or false like onclick=return functionname();

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do it is setting onsubmit action in your form like this:

```
<form id="contactform" action="<?= base_url(); ?>" method="post" onsubmit="return check_email()">
```

And then in your javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function check_email() {

    var name = $.trim($('#name').val());

    if (name == "") {
        error = true;
        errortext = "<p>Please enter a name.</p>";
    }

    if (error) {
        $('#error_text').html(errortext);
        return false;
    } 

    return true;
}
```

Hope it helps.